# coalesce and repartition not changing changing number of partitions after flatmap

Tags: python, pyspark, transformation, spark-submit, flatmap

I have a dataframe I am performing some transformations on. I am re-partitioning the dataframe in order to achieve max parallelism. I print the number of partitions after a set of transformations to verify.

However, after my flatmap transformation, after setting the number of partiiotns and printing the number of partitions, I can  clearly see the number of partitions have not changed.

**Heres my code:**

```
source_df = spark.read.json("some_json.json", multiLine=True).repartition(24)
pprint("number of partitions in source df is {0}".format(source_df.rdd.getNumPartitions()))

transformed_rdd = source_df.select("data").rdd.flatMap(transform_data).repartition(24)
pprint(f"number of partitions in  transformed_rdd is {0}".format(transformed_rdd.getNumPartitions()))
```

**Heres my output:**

```
number of partitions in source df is 24
number of partitions in  transformed_rdd is 0
```

**As you can see the number of partitions after the flatmap becomes 0. I have tried using both coalesce and repartition**

**Why did I choose 24 partitions?**

I am running this spark job on an AWS EMR cluster.I have one master node, and one slave node. My master node is of instance type c5.2xlarge and the slave node is an m5a.xlarge. The master node contains 8 vCPUs and the slave node contains 4.

I have calculate the number of partitions on my dataframe to ideally be 24, this calculation comes from a [best practices documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/) released by AWS

```
spark.default.parallelism = spark.executor.instances * spark.executors.cores * 2
```

**I am running Spark 2.4 on python 3.6**

Thank you

Comment: can you share the transform_data function as well.

Comment: This seems to be happening because the flatMap function will not preserve partitioning. It . will help if you post the full script here.